Can the Google My Business API still be used at this time?
Currently I want to integrate Google My Business in my CRM application, is that possible? because I understand that the business communication API library and the Business message library no longer exist.
I found the information "Google's Business Messages has been deprecated and will be discontinued on July 31, 2024". and I hope to explain this.

shift to Google Business Profile APIs,
